# HyperlinkedRelatedFIeld and OneToOne relationship - object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For my app I have offices and HR users (users with an OneToOneField to HRProfile), and I want to be able to assign HRs to offices. The issue I'm facing is that I just can't access the User's 'email' field when trying to look it up through a HyperlinkedRelatedField on an OfficeSerializer.
Relevant models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
...
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
...

from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel
class Profile(PolymorphicModel):
...    
    related_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="profile",
    )
...

class HRProfile(Profile):
    some_hr_specific_field = models.CharField()    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.related_user.email

class Office(models.Model):
...
    assigned_hrs = models.ManyToManyField(
        "users.HRProfile", related_name="offices", blank=True
    )
...
```

View:

```
class UserViewSet(
    GenericViewSet,
):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "email"
    lookup_url_kwarg = "email"
    lookup_value_regex = "[\\w@.]+"
...
# the OfficeViewSet just has the two required fields (queryset and serializer)
```

And the OfficeSerializer I'm having trouble with:

```
class OfficeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
...
    assigned_hrs = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=HRProfile.objects.all(),
        view_name="api:user-detail",
        lookup_field="related_user.email",
        many=True,
    )
...
```

The above raises `'HRProfile' object has no attribute 'related_user.email'` which I don't know what to make of, since the `HRProfile.__str__` has no issues resolving the `self.related_user.email` path correctly for a given user.

I tried it with `source='assigned_hrs.related_user', lookup_field='email'` but to no avail. Also, I tried replacing the HyperlinkedRelatedField with an SlugRelatedField just to test, and it's the same issue with the `slug_field="related_user.email"`.

I also tried using the double underscores instead of a period. What goes through however is `lookup_field='some_hr_specific_field'` which is surely not what I want, but it does resolve.

So I'm really running out of ideas, and any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Define get_hrs on Office model:

```
class Office(models.Model):
    def get_hrs(self):
        hrs = self.assigned_hrs.all()
        return [hr.related_user for hr in hrs]
```

And simply use the method as `source`:

```
class OfficeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    assigned_hrs = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=User.objects.filter(groups__name="human_resource"),
        source="get_hrs",
        lookup_field="email",
        view_name="api:user-detail",
    )
    # slugrelated works too :)
    # assigned_hrs = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    #     many=True,
    #     queryset=User.objects.filter(groups__name="human_resource"),
    #     source="get_hrs",
    #     slug_field="email",
    # )
```